# Cannot link the icon resource

Tags: delphi, resources, icons, delphi-5

I try to add an icon in my Delphi 5 project and compile/link it, but get the following error:

"[Error] RLINK32: Out of memory!"

What is the problem?

The icon is at http://www.shuling.net/temp/Project2.zip

Answer (score 3):

Your icons include large style 256px icons that were introduced in the Vista time frame. The Delphi 5 tooling is incapable of linking them. As I recall, the `brcc32` from Delphi 5 cannot handle these icons because 256px icons are represented in a .ico file as having size `0`. They are also stored with PNG compression to keep the size manageable. The `brcc32` from Delphi 5 knows nothing of this and simply cannot handle it.

When I was linking such icons to my old Delphi 6 projects I used the Microsoft resource compiler, `rc.exe` to compile the resources. The Delphi linker from Delphi 6 was able to link the compiled `.res` files.

I'm not sure whether or not the Delphi 5 linker will be able to do even that. If not then you will need a post-build action to link the resource to the file. However, if I recall correctly, all I had to do was use `rc.exe` to compile the `.rc` file to `.res`, and then let Delphi link that.

So, in summary you need to:

1. Compile the `.rc` file with a modern resource compiler, for example `rc.exe`.
2. Link the resulting `.res` file in the usual way with `$R` if Delphi 5 can do so. If it cannot, use a separate post-build too to link the `.res` file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Which resource ID should I use for the icon in .rc file, since the icon is the application's main icon.

Comment: You have to call it MAINICON because that's the name the VCL uses

Comment: Thanks. I try but get a warning said "Duplicate resources". How to remove the original icon for the project and use the one in the external .res file?

Comment: The other one is probably in projname.res. Linked with $R *.res in the .dpr file. Remove that.